# нет result в программе JSFiddle

Tags: jsfiddle

Почему в программа JSFiddle в окне результат ничего не пишется .,когда пишу на JAve? Подскажите как это работает.

Comment: А почему он должен писа́ться-то?

Comment: И кстати jsfidlle не поддерживает код на Java.

Comment: В верхнем левом углу, кнопка "Run"... или в правом углу "Settings" → "Auto-run code"

Comment: правильно понял что на JSFiddleписать на JAVA нельзя. кнопку runнажимаю но в окне ничего не появляется, поэтому и спрашиваю

Comment: А почему в окне должно что-то появляться?

Comment: ну результат кода должен ведь появляется? программа ведь для этого

Comment: вот как в этой программе https://www.jdoodle.com/online-java-compiler/

Comment: Код вывода результата должен быть написан в коде. Программа по этой ссылке вполне содержит код вывода. А что вы там у себя в jsfiddle понаписали — чёрт вас знает, вы ж стесняетесь рассказать, что именно вы на jsfiddle делаете

Comment: я просто написал туда для теста 
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
     
      System.out.println("hello world");
    }
}

Comment: Ещё раз: jsfiddle не поддерживает код на Java. Откройте консоль браузера, и вы увидите сообщение о синтаксической ошибке, потому что вы попытались запихнуть Java-код туда, где он не поддерживается.

Comment: а как тогда в jsfiddle писать на java. никак? и спасибо что отвечаете.

Comment: Никак конечно, в браузерах Java нету.

Comment: ясно . спасибо.